# Check for extension library and redirect to Notes

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to implement an XPages application to run in the Client.  The application currently has a Notes view version which is displayed to users by default.  As the application relies on  the extension library I only want the user to get the XPage version if extlib is installed.  If not, then I want to redirect the user back to a Notes element.

So, I see two possible patterns;

**Number 1**

- Launch app to an xpage
- Check for existence of extension library

  - if not present, redirect to Notes element
  - if present, redirect to xpage

**Number 2**

- Launch app to a Notes form/page
- Check for existence of extension library

  - if not present, redirect to Notes element
  - if present, redirect to xpage

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer option 2 - launching XPage takes some time, so in case of redirect back to notes you waste many seconds of user's life...

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
var v = com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getExtLibVersion();
```

in a try ... catch construct . if extlib is present, it will return the version; if it is not installed, it will trow an exception and you can then redirect to the Notes Element

Comment: true, but where to test and how to redirect?

Comment: Thanks Ulrich.  I've got a try/catch working but now its a case of how to redirect to the notes element.

Comment: I've subsequently noticed that the app will not even load the xpage if the library is not installed, therefore any redirect page will not work. So the try/catch doesn't work.

Comment: So, then you have to check from LS, if the extlib plugin is installed. I think that this can be done in it's easiest way, by just checking, if the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.xxx exists in the D:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins directory, where D:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\ is the NotesDataDir.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  We're using the upgrade pack which doesn't plant files in the same way as the extension library.  Instead I've wound up searching for a particular key in the platform.xml file.  Working a treat now, thanks.